# Suitescript - How do I access the values in "Subsidiaries" sublist on vendor record?

Tags: netsuite, sublist, suitescript, vendor

On the vendor record, I need to loop over the Subsidiaries sublist through a scripted search, to get all of the values. I am specifically trying to find vendors that do not belong to a particular subsidiary.

UPDATE

To clear up my question, I was trying to access the Subsidiaries sublist and not the actual primary subsidiary. However NetSuite said that this is currently not possible and is a requested enhancement.

Comment: I need to access the relationship between vendors and subsidiaries, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

bluejay92, the vendor search has a join to the subsidiary record, see attach screen shot.  You can even check "use expressions" to gain access to the NOT function in the criteria.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to find the primary subsidiary. I am trying to access the "Subsidiaries" sublist that lists multiple subsidiaries for the vendor. NetSuite told me today that there is actually no way to do this at this time but it is a requested enhancement (unless someone can think of a workaround).

Comment: Are you looking to script this in UserEvent or client-side script?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1 - Create a user event script that runs after the record is created/edited.

2 - Have the script load the record, get the subsidiaries and create a custom record to save the info so you can search it later.

3 - Export all vendors internal ids in 1 column. Run a CSV import of vendors and map internalid csv column to internalid field to trigger the user event script and populate the custom records.

Extra tip: Make sure the script does 'upserts' to the custom record to avoid duplicates. There should be one record per vendor.

Comment: And how would you get the subsidiaries in step 2?

Comment: On SS 1.0: record.getLineItemValue('submachine','subsidiary', 1);     where 1 is the line index number, submachine is the sublist where the subsidiaries are stored and subsidiary is the column field id